# First launch and after update alert android

Tags: java, android, launch

I want my application(android) to go to another activity on the first launch, so people immediately change their settings. After I update my application I want to show a changelog. I know you can make this happen with shared preferences and I made something like this:

```
package me.wouter.schoolwork;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class Updater extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.update);
    checkFirstLaunch();
}

public void checkFirstLaunch(){
    boolean firstrun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true);
    if (firstrun){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Welcome").setMessage("Welcome on  ").setNeutralButton("OK", null).show();

    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .edit()
        .putBoolean("firstrun", false)
        .commit();
    }
}
```

}

I'm not sure if this works, and this doesn't work for updating. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I ran your code, and it is showing dialog on first launch. What problem are you facing?

Comment: If this also works on updating the application..

Comment: Sure, it will. You have to keep track of current version of your app. Try the answer posted below.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int currentVersion = 0;
    try {
        currentVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getSherlockActivity().getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS).versionCode;
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    final int lastVersion = prefs.getInt("lastVersion", -1);
    if (currentVersion > lastVersion) {
        showChangelogDialog();
        prefs.edit().putInt("lastVersion", currentVersion).commit();
    }
```

Comment: Okay thank you, but does this also work on the first launch (version 1)

Comment: You can see that when there is no record in SharedPreferences yet, the default value is -1. Then 1>-1 and changelog is shown.